# Why my header animation does not work using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my `header` `height` change when I scroll down the page, but for one or another reason it doesn't work. I already tried putting the `console.log` to check if that works and that does work.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const header = document.querySelector("header");

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 50) {
      console.log("heeeeeeeey");
      header.style.height = "50px";
    } else {
      header.style.height = "12vh";
    }
  });
};
```

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--color3);
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0px 120px;
  min-height: 12vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: var(--titleFont);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a>name</a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: When you set the minimum height to 12vh, setting the height to 50px will not have any effect.

Comment: @Gerard damn that was the stupid problem. thanks!

Comment: If you indeed remove the `min-height` your problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

## min-height overriding

The code here only has only one problem, and it's in the CSS.
Just **remove the min-height property from header** selector

Lets check the header selector:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--color3);
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0px 120px;
  min-height: 12vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: var(--titleFont);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

The **min-height** property always overrides both **height** and **max-height**.

> min-height: 12vh;

Look at the next JS code:

```
if (window.scrollY > 50) {
  console.log("heeeeeeeey");
  header.style.height = "50px";
}
```

Here when you set **header.style.height = "50px"** it doesn't matter, because as the min-height overrides height, the size is not going to change.

To more info about this, check this docs
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-height/